# MemoryCache save to file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, memorycache

I am using MemoryCache to cache values in my MVC web app. Is it possible to save MemoryCache collection values to file and latter load them?

Answer (score 0):

Think it theoretically possible, using reflection copy all data to some simple json object, then serialize it as string and store on disk. When need to retrieve object, so you need again with help of reflection build new MemoryCache instance from json.

Maybe it also some variants with binary serialization or casting object to byte stream and then saving.

Answer (score -1):

You can [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8)

that is a sample

```
public static class Cashing
    {
        public static void SetData<T>(string CacheKey, T data)
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(CacheKey))
                cache.Remove(CacheKey);
            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
            cache.Add(CacheKey, data, cacheItemPolicy);
        }

        public static object GetData<T>(string CacheKey)
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(CacheKey))
                return cache.Get(CacheKey);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```